# Stocks app crashes on launch after moving from iPhone to iPad on iOS 6.1.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, jailbreak, crash

I want to port the Stocks app from iPhone to iPad. I transferred Stocks.app and the relevant frameworks files from iPhone 4 iOS 6.1.3 to iPad 2 iOS 6.1.3. The files are zipped via iFile on iPhone and unzipped into the right directories when the files are on iPad 2 so that the proper file permission can be preserved. Weather, compass and voice memo works, however this Stocks always crash at opening.

[image: crash report]

Answer (score 1):

The crash log shows that /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Stocks.framework/Stocks can't be loaded because it can't be found. Make sure you have copied the entire Stocks.framework into the correct location with identical permissions applied (unzipping in iFile will **not** preserve permissions so you'll need to set them yourself recursively).

Comment: This problem occur even I had copied the entire stocks.framework folder. You mean I have to set the permission for all files manually?

Comment: @Zheung Yes, when you extracted the zip in iFile all the files are set to mobile owner and other incorrect permissions. You'll need to set them all appropriately.

Comment: I checked, all the permission are same with the files on iPhone. One thing I forgot to mention is, when I tap the app icon, the screen just flash a black screen. This means that even the "default" image is unable to load. Any help will be appreciated.